# Not able to modify Codable Class Properties?

Tags: swift, properties, codable

New in Swift development. I have a class structure for my USER JSON. I am able to encode JSON value to User object but when I want to modify these properties changes not reflected in a class structure. Can you please help me.

```
import Foundation
struct UserInfo : Codable {
let userId : String?
var firstName : String?
var lastName : String?
let email : String?
let phone : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case userId = "userId"
    case firstName = "firstName"
    case lastName = "lastName"
    case email = "email"
    case phone = "phone"

}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    userId = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .userId)
    firstName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    lastName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
    email = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
    phone = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .phone)

}
//trying with mutating function but not able to modify
mutating func update(firstName fName: String) {
    self.firstName = fName
}

mutating func update(email newMail: String) {
    self.email = newMail
}
}
```

encode to User Object

```
 let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
 let responseModel = try jsonDecoder.decode(LoginResponseBody.self, from: data)
 if let userInfo = responseModel.responseBody {
  // get userInfo object
  print(userInfo.firstName) // output: Vishal
 }
```

My question is how can i modify above object values and also it's a var type

when i tried

```
userInfo.firstName = "something other"
print(userInfo.firstName)// output: Vishal
```

Again same result

also tried with mutating func

```
userInfo.update(firstName: "something other")
print(userInfo.firstName) // output: Vishal
```

Not able to modify existing values.

Comment: Unrelated but if the property names match the coding keys you can omit both the coding keys and the initializer. And why are all properties optional? Do you really have a user without name and user id?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your issue is – please could you provide a [mcve]? Although if your properties are `let` constants, you won't be able to mutate them.

Comment: @Hamish Please see my updated question.

Comment: @Vishal16 `if var userInfo`

Comment: @Vishal16 What's `LoginResponseBody`? If `userInfo` is a `let` (and is of type `UserInfo`), I would expect `userInfo.firstName = "something other"` to be a compiler error. Again, a minimal self-contained example would be really useful here.

Comment: Okay. I will try and update you.

Answer (score -1):

Change let to var when declaring userInfo;

```
if var userInfo = responseModel.responseBody {
  // get userInfo object
  userInfo.firstName = "something other"
  print(userInfo.firstName)
 }
```