# Encode / Decode Structs using Encodable / Decodable from Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm not so used to structs and the only way I know to use structs is like so...

```
struct UserDetails {
  let name: String
  let message: String

  init(name: String, message: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.message = message
  }
}
```

And once I receive the values of `name` and `message`, I add them to the struct like so...

`let userDetails = UserDetails(name: theName, message: theMessage)`

This is then added to an array of the struct type like so...

```
self.userDetailsArray.append(userDetails)
```

Now finally, when I want to get the individual name or mesasge, I get it like so...

```
let user = userDetailsArray[indexPath.row]
cell.userNameLabel.text = user.name
cell.messageLabel.text = user.message
```

This works fine also. But my concern is this...what I have specified above is a very old method since swift has come up with `NSCoding` and then `Codable` protocols also. But I don't know how to implement them.

Hope someone can show how I can apply `NSCoding/Codable` protocols to the example I have mentioned above...

Comment: You have not shown any code that would be relevant to `NSCoding`, where do you think about using it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

Comment: `Codable` is only useful if you need to (de)serialize the data from/to JSON or Property List data otherwise your *very old method* is perfectly fine.

Comment: .@luk2302 The encoders and decoders come after the init method I feel...But how it is to be used I'm not sure. Also encoders and decoders handle the parsing part automatically right..? Thats what I wanted to know..

Comment: I'm sorry @vadian..But could u just explain what exactly `serialize the data to JSON or Property List ` mean..? Does it mean converting to json..?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375826/not-able-to-modify-codable-class-properties this question will help you.

Comment: Yes it means *converting to*...

Comment: Thanks @vadian. But consider I want to (de)serialize the data from/to JSON. Then how can I achieve it in my case..?

Comment: Please look at the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine. To apply Codable for parsing/storing/retrieving your user details list, you need to define your struct like bellow,

```
struct UserDetails: Codable {
    let name: String
    let message: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        //Uncomment the following commentted lines, if your JSON formatted data comes with different keys like bellow
        case name       //= "user_name"
        case message    //= "user_message"
    }

    init(name: String, message: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.message = message
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(message, forKey: .message)
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
    }
}
```

To parse response from making web api call, you can use the following function

```
func makeAPICall(){
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.your-web-api") else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let userDetails = try decoder.decode([UserDetails].self, from: data)
            print(userDetails)
        } catch let err {
            print("Error", err)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

To store your user details list, you can write like this function

```
func storeUserDetails(userDetails: [UserDetails]) {
    do {
        let data = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(userDetails)
        let success = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(data, toFile: filePath(key: "file.archive"))
        print(success ? "Successful save" : "Save Failed")
    } catch {
        print("Save Failed")
    }
}
```

To retrieve your user detail list use this function

```
func retrieveUserDetails() -> [UserDetails]? {
    guard let data = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath(key: "file.archive")) as? Data else { return nil }
    do {
        let products = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([UserDetails].self, from: data)
        return products
    } catch {
        print("Retrieve Failed")
        return nil
    }
}
```

And the helper function to get the file path

```
func filePath(key:String) -> String {
    let manager = FileManager.default
    let url = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    return (url!.appendingPathComponent(key).path)
}
```

**Some good reads:**

1. [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)
2. [Encoding, Decoding and Serialization in Swift 4](https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4)
3. [Everything about Codable in Swift 4](https://hackernoon.com/everything-about-codable-in-swift-4-97d0e18a2999)

Comment: Writing own `encode(to: Encoder)` and `init(from: Decoder)` is quite an overdoing it here. Also, for sake of showing example of custom coding keys I guess it's better to not duplicate `case` in commented out section but just comment out `= "<custom coding key string>"` like `case name // = "user_name"`. Or newcomer may just uncomment those commented out cases and get case duplicates and compile error, and will be confused.

Comment: What is the questioner get response runtime error because his calling server responded with different key string. Won't the questioner be confused? At least he can try with these option to find out & learn more.

Comment: I have nothing agains adding example how to use custom keys, i'm just saying it would be more expressive to have `case name // = "user_name" // uncomment it, if you need custom key` instead of `case name … \n // uncomment it, if you need custom key \n // case name = "user_name" ` in first case you just remove `//` before `=` and you get working code. In your case you also have to not forget to delete first `case name`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MehediHasan. Please don't mind if I'm asking this...could u also show how from your example how to finally call the `retrieveUserDetails` function to get the required data..?

Comment: if you're trying on an iOS project, create a swift file with the struct definition & add all the rest functions to a ViewController class. call the retrieve function like bellow in viewDidLoad function
`if let userDetails = retrieveUserDetails() {
        print(userDetails)
    } else{
        print("Retrieve Failed")
    }`

Comment: There is no reason for the hand coded `init`. You get that exact `init` for free from this `struct`. Same for the `encode` and `decode` methods. Don't write code that you don't need to write.

Comment: @rmaddy You're right! But I think our questioner is novice. So my answer lefts room for him to speculate around those functions and learn more.

Comment: But your answer makes it look a lot harder than it needs to be. That's the opposite of what you want for a novice. Show minimal code. They can discover the flexibility of custom written code when it is actually needed.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy....would you mind pointing out which code is actually enough to replicate the scenario I have mentioned in the question...?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of Example you can find on internet. Here is generic function which uses `Codable` protocol. Let's take your example:

```
struct UserDetails: Codable {
  let name: String, message: String
}
```

Now let's have a look at wonderful extension from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/eMdOS/88a465e8898a0600d0a343e148d6bef1):

```
extension Encodable {
    func encode(with encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) throws -> Data {
        return try encoder.encode(self)
    }
}

extension Decodable {
    static func decode(with decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), from data: Data) throws -> Self {
        return try decoder.decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

Which does nothing but a simple function to `encode` and `decode` values based on `Class` specified.

Now, it becomes simpler like you have to just pass the `data` receiving from the `API`.

```
if let arrUserDetails: [UserDetails] = try? [UserDetails].decode(from: data!) {
    print("UserDetails \(arrUserDetails)")   
}
```

This is how you can use latest `Encodable` and `Decodable` protocols.

Comment: Thanks @Sohil R. Memon. I went through the link u provided and there is this certain line..`let lang: Language? = try? Language.decode(from: data!)` Could u just say what will printing `lang` give me..? Will I get `lang.name = "Swift"` and `lang.version = "4"`...?

Comment: Yes that's the explanation like how to use! You can refer my answer on how to solve your problem! @v.bw

Comment: Ok @Sohil R. Memon. But one concern...@vadian pointed out in the comments that "encoders/decoders are used when we want to convert to json" But in the example u suggested, are we converting to json...? Because at the end we are finally getting the individual values in the same way as I got them as I stated in the question itself..is it..?